# How to add document in existing nested documents dynamically in mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb

i have following structure

```
{
  "name": "abc",
  "lname": "xyz",
  "data": {
    "1": {
      "info": {
        "test": "test"
      },
      "info1": {
        "test": "test"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

now i want to add following object in 'data' object

```
 "2": {
      "info": {
        "test": "test1"
      },
      "info1": {
        "test": "test1"
      }
    }
```

how to do that in mongodb using mongodb java driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MongoDB shell you can do it as below :

```
db.collection.update( {_id:id} , { $set: { "data.2": 
  {
 "info": {"test": "test1" }, "info1": {"test": "test1"}
  } 
}});
```

In Java driver :

```
DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("_id", "123"); 
DBObject update = new BasicDBObject(); 
DBObject info = new BasicDBObject("test","test1");
update.put("$set", new BasicDBObject("data.2",
new BasicDBObject("info",info).append("info1",info)); 

collection.update(query, update);
```

Comment: thank you yathish for response. this query executed successfully but not appending data to existing document object

Comment: oops!! instead of "data.2" field i had used "name.2" i have updated the same in the post.

Comment: i was already made that change in my mongo query but then also it is not working :( have you tested the same?

Comment: yes i have tested the query in the mongo shell.. its working fine.. can u share the results which you are getting after executing this query ?

Comment: {
 "_id" : ObjectId("55a6090062aefdae06f290b0"),
 "name" : "abc",
 "lname" : "xyz",
 "data" : {
  "1" : {
   "info" : {
    "test" : "test"
   },
   "info1" : {
    "test" : "test"
   }
  }
 }
}
i have this record in my test databse and i am running following query db.test1.update( {name:"abc"},{ $set: { "data.2":   {  "info": {"test": "test1" }, "info1": {"test": "test1"}   }  }}); this shows nothing in console and my data remains same in database

Comment: Its working perfectly fine. I used the same update query which you have given. I first executed with { upsert: true } option.. Then i again ran the same update query by changing the "data.2" to "data.3". I can see a new documnet " 3" being created along existing documnets in "data" filed.